# Updating Dataset with Some Corrected Information, Some New Information

Tags: sas

I have an old dataset with yearly record high temperatures for a number of cities. Each observation has seven variables: City State Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 Year5

I also have a new dataset with yearly record high temperatures for an overlapping range of years. Each observation has seven variables: City State Year3 Year4 Year5 Year6 Year7

Some of the cities in the new dataset are the same as those in the old dataset, some are entirely new. I would like to combine the two datasets into one with nine variables: City State Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 Year5 Year6 Year7

For those cities that appear in both datasets, the situation is complicated. For the overlapping years, Year3 Year4 Year5, non-missing values in the new dataset indicate a correction to the old dataset, and these non-missing values in the new dataset should appear in the merged dataset; missing values in the new dataset indicate no correction to the old dataset, and the values in the old dataset should appear in the merged dataset.

How best to merge the two datasets under these circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update should work for you. below example should work. 2nd dataset updates records of first one when only 2nd dataset has value(it does not update with missing value). it also add's new cities from 2nd data please try running the example below.

```
data old_dataset;
input City $ State $ Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 Year5;
datalines;
 city1 state1 90 80 70 60 50
 city3 state3 90 80 . 60 50
 ;

data new_dataset;
 input City $ State $ Year1 Year2 Year3 Year4 Year5 Year6 Year7;
datalines;
city1 state1 . . . . . . .
city2 state2 90 80 70 60 50 90 80
city3 state3 90 80 90 60 . 60 50
;

proc sort data=old_dataset;
by city;
run;

proc sort data=new_dataset;
by city;
run;

data want;
update old_dataset new_dataset;
by city;
run;
```

After update following things happen
1. new columns are added
2. Non missing values of 2nd dataset updates column of first dataset .